# take first array of subarray with rxjs

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I try to take first array of a sub array. So I have it like this:

```
  Map: map;

 Map() {
    Service
      
        });
  }
```

and this is the interface:

```
export interface map { 
   
}
```

But I get this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'heatmap' of undefined
```

so what I have to change?

I still get this error:

```
core.js:4442 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null
```

```
.pipe(map((res) => res.map.slice(0, 1)))
```

and this is how I have it:

```
 Map() {
    
        });
  }
```

yes,

so I have this now:

```
 dMap() {

    console.log(this.Map.map);

    this.Service
      
        });
  }
```

But when I hover the mouse over this line:

```
console.log(this.Map.heatmap);
```

Comment: Your cameraAgretateHeadMap property is undefined. Just initialize it before your subscription.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change

```
 cameraAgretateHeadMap: CameraAggregationHeatmap;
```

to

```
 cameraAgretateHeadMap: CameraAggregationHeatmap = {};
```

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: Oke, I see now that heatmap has 100 elements. But I still dont see anything in the view. So yes, the data is loaded. But I dont anything on the web page.

Comment: @CodeIsNice, that's a separate issue, you can raise separate stackoverflow question for that.